# Python requests library HTTPBasicAuth with three parameters

Tags: python, http

I'm trying to use [Instapaper's simple developer api](https://www.instapaper.com/api/simple) to add a url to my bookmarks using python and the requests library. To authenticate the username and password all works well.

```
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
requests.get('https://www.instapaper.com/api/authenticate', auth=HTTPBasicAuth('username', 'password'))
```

But when trying to use the api to add a bookmark:

```
 requests.get('https://www.instapaper.com/api/add', auth=HTTPBasicAuth('username', 'password','websiteUrl'))
```

I get error:

```
File "instantbookmark.py", line 3, in <module>
   getA = requests.get('https://www.instapaper.com/api/add',     auth=HTTPBasicAuth('username', 'password','websiteUrl'))
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 3 arguments (4 given)
```

I think this is because HTTPBasicAuth can't take a third argument, does anyone know a way to do this?

Comment: That is the full traceback error

Comment: Yeah, I checked the source of requests and the documentation of the API, see my answer below.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`HTTPBasicAuth()` only *ever* takes username and password arguments. There is no 3rd argument, full-stop.

HTTP Basic Authentication adds an extra header to the request; this information is kept separate from the GET or POST parameters. When you use this form of authentication, you do not need to pass any `username` and `password` parameters to the API methods either.

To add a bookmark, pass in the `url` parameter as a POST or GET data parameter:

```
 requests.post('https://www.instapaper.com/api/add', data={'url': 'websiteUrl'}, auth=HTTPBasicAuth('username', 'password'))
```

Either `requests.get()` or `requests.post()` will do.

Comment: Is there any difference if I use res=requests.get('site', auth=('user_name', 'pass')) & res=requests.get('site', auth=HTTPBasicAuth('user_name', 'pass'))?

Comment: @Gourab: no, no difference. Passing a tuple of length 2 (username and password) to `auth` is translated into a `HTTPBasicAuth()` object. See the [source code of `requests`](https://github.com/psf/requests/blob/d09659997cd1e3eca49a07c59ece5557071c0ab9/requests/models.py#L553-L555).